# JSTREE link/ node for longer length names is not properly rendered in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, sharepoint-2010, jstree

[image: Jstree in Chrome]

[image: Jstree in FireFox/IE]

Jstree rendered in Chrome:(upper Image)

Jstree rendered in FireFox /IE( lower Image)
    I use the following properties in the css:

```
 {word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space:normal;
    max-width:180px;
    }
```

Any help in why jstree link behaves like this in Chrome is appreciated.
Thank you  and regards.

ps: I forgot to add that the above is a web part in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a fixed height on the list items. I'd set a width on the container element and remove the max-width in your CSS. Also, I assume the paragraph of text is only an example, and you'd not actually need a menu item that long :)

Can you post any more code / HTML so that we can take a better look?